# pdf annotations

Tags: comments, dvi, annotations, yap

There is a package `pdfcomments` to place annotations in the pdf. However, when producing DVI output, yap gives errors. I do not mind not seeing the annotations in the DVI, but I do mind seeing the errors. Is there a way to suppress the annotations if the file produced is a DVI?

Comment: Why do you need dvi anyway? Is there a reason why you cannot compile with pdflatex?

Comment: Simple, pdf cannot be rewritten while open, dvi can, I can quickly make changes to latex source, compile, see the change. In pdf, I have to close the file, compile and open, if I forget, vim crashes. So it is just about being effective, dvi is much faster for quick previews.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Hi. Apparently you don't use an appropriate editor like Texmaker. In addition some other pdf viewers like sumatra allow to have the pdf open.

Comment: I am using vim + vim-latex + acrobat reader. There is another issue, for DVI, they are compiled and recompiled as many times as necessary to update references, with pdf, the recompilation has to be done manually.

Comment: If you choose to keep using dvi, then the `final` option of `pdfcomment` may be useful (turns off all annotations), possibly combined with the `ifpdf` package to automatically detect whether you are compiling to dvi or to pdf.

Comment: Did that option help? Or were you able to switch to a productive pdf setup?